# "Number of zeroes of $f \leq \deg f$" used in a proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> If a field K is infinite, then the map
>
> $$°: ~~~ K[t] \rightarrow AllMaps(K,K), ~~~ f \mapsto f° $$
>
> is injective.

(*K[t]* is the space of all polynomials in the variable *t*, with coefficients in *K*. I don't quite get the difference between *f* and *f°*. One looks like $a_0t^0+ \cdots+a_nt^n$ and the other $a_0 \lambda ^0+ \cdots+a_n \lambda ^n$, where $\lambda \in K$.)

*Proof.* Let $f_1,f_2 \in K[t]$ and $g:=f_2-f_1.$ If $f_1^°=f_2^°$, then $g^°=0$, i.e. $g(\lambda)=0$ for all $\lambda \in K$. So *g* has infinitely many zeroes and from corollary 1 it follows that $g=0$, and therefore $f_1=f_2$.

Corollary 1 is that the number of zeros of some fuction is lower or equal to its degree.
In this book the degree of the zero-polynomial is defined to be $-\infty$.

I get that the main idea is to show that "if f(x)=f(y), then x=y, hence injective".

But what I don't understand is the application of the corollary: $g$ has infinitely many zeros **and** its degree is $-\infty$, which rather contradicts the corollary.

**Inhowfar does the corollary affect the proof?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corollary 1, as stated in your question obviously fails for the zero polynomial, and if properly stated, should be prefaced with: "for a non-zero polynomial...".

Having said that, the proof works as follows: Suppose $g$ is not the zero polynomial. Then it can not have more roots than its degree. This contradicts Corollary 1.

Also, $f$ and $f^\circ$ are not the same thing; $f$ is a polynomial in the formal sense: an expression of the form $a_0t^0+\cdots+a_nt^n$. To such a polynomial we can associate a function $K\to K$ given by $f^\circ:x\mapsto f(x)$. The theorem in your question says that when the field is infinite, there is no harm in confusing $f$ and $f^\circ$. However, when $K$ is finite, note that there are infinitely many polynomials in $K[t]$, but only finitely many functions $K\to K$, so there must be examples where $f \neq g$ but $f^\circ = g^\circ$. As a concrete example, if $K$ is the field with $q$ elements, $f(t) = t$, $g(t) = t^q$, then $f^\circ = g^\circ$.

Comment: Are polynomials always of finite degree?

Comment: Non-zero polynomials certainly are.

Comment: I know it's disappreciated but thank you, now everything is *glasklar*.

Comment: Gern geschehen!